# How to get history of a state in corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

In My corda project state may evolve over time. I have made the state of type LinearState. Now I want to retrieve the history of a corda state that means, How it evolved over time. How can I see the evolution history of a particular state in Corda?

Particularly, I want to access the complete transaction chain of a state.

Answer (score 0):

Of course without access to your code this answer will vary, but there's two pieces of documentation to be aware of here.

What you want to perform is essentially a vault query (depending on what information you're looking to get).

From the docs on `LinearState`:

> Whenever a node records a new transaction, it also decides whether it should store each of the transaction’s output states in its vault. The default vault implementation makes the decision based on the following rules.

source: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-states.html#the-vault

That being said, to perform your vault query you would do it just like you would other states. Here's the docs on the vault query API : https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-vault-query.html

If you have the linear Id you can do it from the node shell or using H2 and looking in places like the VAULT_LINEAR_STATES table.

If you want an example of querying in code take a look at the obligation cordapp that takes the linearID as a parameter to the flow.

```java
           // 1. Retrieve the IOU State from the vault using LinearStateQueryCriteria
            List<UUID> listOfLinearIds = Arrays.asList(stateLinearId.getId());
            QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, listOfLinearIds);
            Vault.Page results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(IOUState.class, queryCriteria);
            StateAndRef inputStateAndRefToSettle = (StateAndRef) results.getStates().get(0);
            IOUState inputStateToSettle = (IOUState) ((StateAndRef) results.getStates().get(0)).getState().getData();
```

Source Code example here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/flows/IOUSettleFlow.java#L56-L61